# Extract external domain xml data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, cors

I have an error in the browser when extracting the xml data from an external domain through jquery ajax.

I try to do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
     url: "http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=E8FBFBE1-E50F-4E6A-BEA7-CA2E41F96D0B&apikey=cf41bd17-7638-4c10-b869-341555a65d7f&type=xml&previous=yes&next=yes&cover=yes&callmeback=yes&defaultcover=yes" ,
dataType: "xml" ,   
 success: function(xml) {


    var title = $(xml).find('title').text(),  
    artist = $(xml).find('artists').text(); 



Actc(title, artist);


    }

});
```

I have that ajax request within a setinterval that updates the data every 20 seconds.

It goes well for a while, but then gives this error in the browser (Chrome) and stops reading the xml information:

*Failed to load http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=XXXXXXXX&apikey=xxxxxxx&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.canal' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.*

I have searched for information but I can not get clear. It seems that it is not possible to extract xml content from a different domain with ajax unless **CORS** is enabled on my server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Although I tried to add it to .htaccess without success, since I kept giving the error. I have also tried to do it by php but also without success. Surely I do something wrong, I'm not very expert in this regard.

**htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
  Header add Content-Type: "application/json"
</IfModule>
```

How could I extract the XML data without **CORS** problems?

Comment: No... unless CORS is enabled on the server you're trying to get the data from

Comment: I think Radionomy does not have it enabled. They say here: https://board.radionomy.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=26734

I have tried that solution and it gives the same error. Would there be any other way to extract that data?

Comment: The OP of that thread was having the same problem as you. And built a tool to get around it

Comment: You can simply make the request on your sever and then send the xml to your client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the CORS it refers to the remote server, not your own. So the Radionomy need to enable it on their server.

But you mention that it works coorect for a bit, which implies that they correctly set it (*those times*).

So unless it is an issue on their side, it could be that in their api docs, the `callmeback` value that the request returns, specifies when the next query should occur. But you have hardcoded it to 20 seconds. Perhaps they are blocking you because you try too soon and they consider it abuse.

---

Another way to bypass the CORS is for your ajax call to call a page on your server which will be the one to make the remote call to the API. That is because CORS is only in effect when the call is made from the browser.

Comment: I had not thought about that, what would be the right time? Could you pass me the url of the api docs?

Comment: @PlayerWet  When you make a request the returned xml includes a node named `callmeback` which contains an integer in milliseconds, i assume, which states when you should make the next request. So instead of an interval you should use a timeout with the delay specified in the returned xml each time.

Comment: Thank you. It was that, time had too short.